# How do you access the content of a ASP.NET control?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this:

```
    <uc1:TestControl ID="TestControl1" runat="server">
        <div>More random HTML, etc...</div>
    </uc1:TestControl>
```

I got an error of "Type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not have a public property named 'div'.".  Doing a little research, I found I could add the following property to the server control:

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
public partial class TestControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Is it possible to read the content from an ASP.NET control?

Edit: Changed wording to reflect that I am curious if you can do this with either a server or user control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a server control, you would create [a property that implements ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx) to contain that content.  I'm not positive whether that is possible in a user control, but it may be.

Answer (score 0):

yeah it is possible

check this MSDN Article about creating templated user controls, plus you can add [ParseChildren(false)] to the user control class so you can see them from the page holding them.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx

hope this helps.